# Shiny for python equivalent of validate()

Tags: python, error-handling, py-shiny

Normally to remove an error message that appears when there has been no input for Shiny in R you can use the validate() function, is there a way to remove this type of error message when using Shiny for python?

I've tried using reactive ui components and a ui.markdown error message but the default error message still appears.

Comment: See https://community.rstudio.com/t/validate-user-input-shiny-for-python/160272 Also can you edit your post to use tag py-shiny instead of shiny which is only for R

Comment: I've tried applying what was suggested in the link but I'm using "@render.table" instead of "@render.text" so I think I  might have to use a different method?

Comment: fixed it by making the nice error messages appear in a pandas dataframe instead of just a text string

Comment: Glad you sorted it. You could copy your code as an answer to help the next person ;)